# Dynamically adding routes to Navigo in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, routes, web-frontend

I'm trying to setup a system that dynamically loads classes and routes related to those classes. For it, I'm using [Navigo](https://github.com/krasimir/navigo) as routing library and it should work like this:

1. The main JS file has a route for each section in my website, and dynamically loads the needed class.
2. When instantiated, the class adds two or more new routes.

Here's the problem: the route that loads the page works fine, and the dynamic ones load just once. This means, if I refresh the site with F5 or pressing Enter in the URL bar, the route won't work.

Aside from trying other routing libraries, I've tried to add wildcards to the main routes so they will resolve with every URL, but then the callbacks are called twice. This is the code I've got so far:

1. To add routes from all the sections:

```js
for (const route in routeArray) {
    if (routeArray[route]['className'] != '') {
        this.router.on(routeArray[route]['route'], () => {
            this.loadClassDynamically(routeArray[route]['className']);
        });
    }
}
```

2. To add new routes in the constructor of the new instantiated class:

```js
this.hash = 'administration/users/';

app.router
.on(this.hash + 'edit/:id', (data, params) => {
    console.log(params);
})
.on(this.hash, () => {
    this.loadPage();
})
.resolve();
```